# How to create an array from a list of variables in another file?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a php file which contains just some variables and their values something like this:

```
<?php
    $first = "value1";
    $second = 'value2';
    $third = 'value3';
    $fourh = 'value4';
?>
```

How could I read this file dynamically and save it in an array?
I could do this by parsing the file but is there a php function which does that?
What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Is that file something you created? You can't easily "parse" a file the way you need it (variables into array, without knowing tons of info beforehand). Instead of making your life miserable, simply stick the values in an array and not in variables and include it. Job done, no need to overcomplicate simple issues. Also, it appears you have an XY problem, so I suggest that instead of trying to do this silly thing, why don't you just explain your entire problem and not your attempted solution?

Comment: I think you can read file line by line and using regex match variable name and value and then insert into array where name is a key. regex : `(\$.*?) = (.*?);`

Comment: you can use $config array to store these variable and after that access these variables any where you need.

Comment: That php file is acutally my `config.inc.php` file. There I have some variables which I will pass to javascrip and  show the users later(both variable name and value).

Comment: I don't know whether it works or not, but did you try with `file_get_contents`

Comment: Well I think `file_get_contents` reads a file into a string not an array.

Comment: explain why do you need this exactly, so i can give you the answer or a better alternative solution.

Comment: This php file is my config.inc.php, and I want to show this to my user- who is an admin of my web application- over an  administration panel -. I don't know if I could make it  more clear :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP has a function: [get_defined_vars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php) that might be useful.

You could leverage this function like so:

```
$currentVars = get_defined_vars();
include 'variables.php';
$fileVars = array_diff(get_defined_vars(), $currentVars);
```

`$fileVars` should be an array containing the variable binding from that file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was looking for such a function! It could be the correct answer I'll check and give you feedback :)

Answer (score 0):

As you say in your comment:

> This php file is my config.inc.php, and I want to show this to my user- who is an admin of my web application- over an administration panel

So you need a better approach, this is going to be painful on the long run.

Rewrite your file as the following:

```
[values]
first = "value1"
second = "value2"
third = "value3"
fourh = "value4"
```

Save it however you want, but i suggest an ".ini" extension (it's not necessary, even ".foo" will be ok)

in your PHP script, call `$ini_array = parse_ini_file("sample.ini");` and voila, `$ini_array` contains what you need.

The manual page for parse_ini_file has more examples and istructions. Take a look: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php

Comment: Thank you! I've learned some thing important from you. I'll take this into considaration for the future. :)